# How do i create this jacquard strap texture

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

How do i create this material in blender

[image]

This is my procedural texture, so far.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks great, so far.. are you asking about creating the lettering, or improving your existing texture?

Comment: Both, creating the lettering and improving the existing texture to look like the reference picture. What i've made so far is the extent of my knowledge. I've been trying to figure it for sometime now.

Comment: I think the number one issue is that you're trying to control color with your procedure, when you should be trying to control bump.  This may require a little reworking, because your color is higher contrast than you'd want for a bump, but recognize that you're going to have to go to sampled textures anyways, at least in part, for the text (which would be an image texture that gets subtracted from bump.)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how do i go about adding a decent amount contrast to get level of bump i am after, as for what I've done so far is the extent of my knowledge